# how to increase the file transferring speed for the below code

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

     public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15123);


            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket);
            File transferFile = new File ("D:\\workspace\\SpringRmiClient.rar");
            byte [] bytearray  = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
            BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending Files...");
            os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("File transfer complete");

      }
}
```

The above program transfers file from one pc to another pc.
However, the speed of file transfer is `low`.
Is there any option available to increase the speed of transferring files?

Comment: Invest in a faster network ;-) Btw, there is no guarantee that `bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);` will read the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and a smaller buffer. This will improve latency considerably:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

At the moment you're not transmitting anything until you've read the entire file. This way you're transmitting the first bytes almost immediately, and you're transmitting the final bytes as soon as you read them.

Your present code also:

- only works for file sizes <= `Integer.MAX_VALUE;`
- only works for files that fit into memory; and
- may not work at all, as you are making the unwarranted assumption that `read()` fills the buffer. It's only mandated to read one or more bytes.

Comment: i tried but it is all so too slow can you suggest another idea

Comment: Too slow compared to what? Do you have any evidence that it can be made as fast as you expect?