# client program read the file very slow in java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.*;
public class Client {

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
        int filesize=2022386;
        int bytesRead;
        int currentTot = 0;

        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.6",15123);
        byte [] bytearray  = new byte [filesize];
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:\\copy.rar");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        currentTot = bytesRead;

        do {
           bytesRead =
              is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));
           if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead;
        } while(bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        socket.close();
      }
}
```

In above is my client code it reads the data from server in very slow manner can you suggest me to increase the transfer speed.can i read video files using this code if not suggest idea to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to incress the file transferring speed for the bellow code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642990/how-to-incress-the-file-transferring-speed-for-the-bellow-code)

Comment: I think the best approach is to read intermediate chunks of data. It's better to grab some and display it to relieve the user's impatience. I believe Google determined that patience span to be roughly .25 sec.